# What is the apt/dpkg equivalent of `pacman -Qs`?

Tags: apt, pacman

Pacman/Rosetta suggests using aptitude or apt-file to perform local package query, however neither are provided in my environment (termux).

```
apt search -a --installed package-name*
```

The above command, i.e. globbing, does not appear to work

ammendments:

- changed the code block to reflect my original intention

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to see all installed packages with `apt`:

```
apt list --installed
```

If you want to see a specific installed package(s):

```
dpkg-query -l | grep package-name

apt list --installed | grep package-name

apt list --installed "*package-name*" "*package-name-2*"

apt search package-name | grep installed
```

Comment: There's usually not even need of grep: `apt list` accepts multiple globex as parameter (eg: `apt list --installed '*ssh*' '*telnet*'`. Do mind the single quotes)

Comment: @A.B That also works. I've added it to my answer.

Comment: My apologies. i meant globbing unquoted search queries was not working*. will ammend my question if needed

Comment: See also `aptitude search` with its [very powerful search syntax](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/aptitude/ch02s04.en.html)